# Matching consecutive lines with same beginning

Tags: shell, awk, grep

I have the following file :

```
1xxxxxxx xxxxx xxxxx
2yyyyyyy yyyyy yyyyy
2yyyyyyy yyyyy yyyyy
1xxxxxxx xxxxx xxxxx
2yyyyyyy yyyyy yyyyy
2yyyyyyy yyyyy yyyyy
1xxxxxxx xxxxx xxxxx
1xxxxxxx xxxxx xxxxx
2yyyyyyy yyyyy yyyyy
2yyyyyyy yyyyy yyyyy
```

I want to match when there is two or more consecutive files beginning with "1".

Means I want to get the lines :

```
1xxxxxxx xxxxx xxxxx
1xxxxxxx xxxxx xxxxx
```

I tried with a grep but I assume it only works line by line, so the following is not working :

```
grep -E $1.*$^1 file.txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this line may work for you:

```
awk '/^1/{i++;a[i]=$0;next}i>1{for(x=1;x<=i;x++)print a[x]}{i=0;delete a}' file
```

example:

```
kent$  cat fi
1xxxxxxx xxxxx xxxxx
2yyyyyyy yyyyy yyyyy
2yyyyyyy yyyyy yyyyy
1xxxxxxx xxxxx xxxxx
2yyyyyyy yyyyy yyyyy
2yyyyyyy yyyyy yyyyy
1here
1we
1want
2yyyyyyy yyyyy yyyyy
1these
1lines
1too
2yyyyyyy yyyyy yyyyy

kent$  awk '/^1/{i++;a[i]=$0;next}i>1{for(x=1;x<=i;x++)print a[x]}{i=0;delete a}' fi
1here
1we
1want
1these
1lines
1too
```

explanation:

```
awk 
'/^1/{i++;a[i]=$0;next}          #if line starts with 1, ++i, save it in array a, read next line
i>1{for(x=1;x<=i;x++)print a[x]} #if till here, line doesn't start with 1. if i>1, it means, there are atleast 2 consecutive lines starting with 1, in array a. print them out
{i=0;delete a}                   #finally clear i and array a
```

Comment: @Jérémie see explanation in answer

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Now I understand it better. I still have one problem : the command doesn't works when the file ends with two lines or more begining with '1'. I know it's because the second condition is not true in this case, so the last array a is not displayed, but I'm not sure how I can modify the command to print this last array a.

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -lne 'print "$p\n$_" if(/^1xxxxxx/ and $p=~/^1xxxxxx/);$p=$_;' your_file
```

Tested below:

```
> cat temp
1xxxxxxx xxxxx xxxxx
2yyyyyyy yyyyy yyyyy
2yyyyyyy yyyyy yyyyy
1xxxxxxx xxxxx xxxxx
2yyyyyyy yyyyy yyyyy
2yyyyyyy yyyyy yyyyy
1xxxxxxx xxxxx xxxxx
1xxxxxxx xxxxx xxxxx
2yyyyyyy yyyyy yyyyy
2yyyyyyy yyyyy yyyyy
> perl -lne 'print "$p\n$_" if(/^1xxxxxx/ and $p=~/^1xxxxxx/);$p=$_;' temp
1xxxxxxx xxxxx xxxxx
1xxxxxxx xxxxx xxxxx
>
```